# Find Minimum Value of Active Chart

Tags: excel, vba

so I am wondering how to scale a chart so that the minimum value of the y-axis becomes the minimum value between all the series that are on the chart. Here is the code that I am working with:

```
 Sub This()

    With Sheets("Plots").ChartObjects("The Chart").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        For i = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
          **find minimum value**
        Next i
     .MinimumScale = miny         
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not find the minimum value in the data set itself rather than going through the chart?

Comment: The code as written will also not work if the `ActiveChart` is different from `The Chart`.  Read More about [With ... End With Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

Comment: I have a bunch of charts so I thought that this would be easier. Also because the data is in a bunch of different ranges. I am also kind of interested in this problem now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim s As Series, mins(), x

    Set cht = Sheets("Plots").ChartObjects("The Chart").Chart

    ReDim mins(1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count)
    x = 1

    For Each s In cht.SeriesCollection
        mins(x) = Application.Min(s.Values)
        x = x + 1
    Next s

    cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Application.Min(mins)

End Sub
```

Comment: this is fantastic! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim maxv As Double = objChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue).MaximumScale()
Dim minv As Double = objChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue).MinimumScale()
```